# PTVS Doesn't detect installed VS2010

Tags: python, windows-installer, ptvs, visual-studio-2010

I want to install PTVS for Visual Studio 10. Every time I run msi package with name "PTVS 2.0 VS 2010" it shows me an error that I have to install VS2010 first but I've already had VS2010 express.

I check some solutions on the internet but it didn't work for me for example I add InstallDir in my registry but still getting that error.

Comment: Extensions don't work with Visual Studio Express. You'll need to least Professional or Higher for these kinds of extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You can install PTVS with the express edition (I have it installed). See [here](https://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PTVS%20Installation). See point 2 under the 'Install VS & PTVS' section. In order to get PTVS installed with the express edition of VS, you will have to install the 'PTVS Integrated' package.

Comment: It's not quite "PTVS with Express edition" - it is rather PTVS with Visual Studio Shell. Shell is separate from and distinct from Express. However, it is also free, so the end result is mostly the same, unless you care about other languages that Express supports but Shell does not (though you can still have Express running side by side with Shell in that case).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't develop the PTVS MSI so therefore this isn't a development question, it's a user question.  You should file a bug with the project and get them to look at it.

That said, I decompiled the MSI and it is looking for a registry value:

VSINSTALLPATH = RegLocator(HKLM\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\@InstallDir)

It's looking for it in the 32bit not 64bit hive so if you are on a 64bit OS check under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6232Node\Microsoft......

Later the property VSINSTALLPATH is used in a launch condition to block installation if the property doesn't have a value.

Comment: That is not the problem, it'll find VS whether on 32-bit or 64-bit OS. The problem is that Express is an isolated SKU and will use a completely different reg key. Which we don't support, because Express doesn't support extensions.

Comment: Then you should specifically state that in the launch condition.  You simply say "Visual Studio 2010 must be installed."  without any qualification which then confuses the user because from their perspective it is.

Comment: I've add that installdir to all the VS 10 folders in registery include 64 and 32 bit

Comment: Yes, it is good point. We actually do show a somewhat more verbose message for VS 2013, which directs you towards Integrated Shell (which is supported), but it still doesn't mention express. I'll file a bug.

BTW, the installer is also open sourced as part of the product - here's where the check happens:
https://pytools.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Python/Setup/PythonToolsInstaller/PythonToolsInstaller.wxs